# The asymptotics of the number of unlabeled graphs with n vertices and q edges

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I am trying to find the asymptotics of the number of unlabeled graphs with n vertices and q edges and I found this paper by E. M. Wright. https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1972-78-06/S0002-9904-1972-13097-0/S0002-9904-1972-13097-0.pdf

Theorems 3 and 5 in this paper are what I am looking for. However, I am unable to find his proofs for those Theorems. Could anyone familiar with the literature give some suggestions on finding the proofs or maybe similar results by others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for a while, I found this https://academic.oup.com/plms/article-abstract/s3-28/4/577/1507165?redirectedFrom=PDF, which contains all the results and proofs.